# Clarification needed for chapter 9 example 15 of Gallian's text 10th edition on the notion of "pulling back" vs "the pullback of..."

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

We assume the following two properties for both elements and subgroups of a group under homomorphisms and also example (example 15) are from Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra 9th edition text.

> $(1)$  Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from a group $G$ to a group $\bar{G}$ and let $g$ be an element of $G.$ Then 
> If $\phi(g)=g'$, then $\phi^{-1}(g')=\{x\in G|\phi(x)=g'\}=gKer\; \phi.\\$

> $(2)$  Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from a group $G$ to a group $\bar{G}$ and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.  Then 
> If $\bar{K}$ is a subgroup of G, then $\phi^{-1}(\bar{K})=\{k\in G| \phi(k)\in \bar{K}\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Both properties $(1)$ and $(2)$ are respectively called the inverse image of $g'$ (or the pullback of $g'$) and the inverse image of $\bar{K}$ (or the pullback of $\bar{K}$)

For the following example which is Example 15 in fore mentioned Gallian's text, is suppose to demonstrate how one can find a subgroup of a group $G$ by "pulling back" a subgroup of a factor group of $G$.

Example 15:  Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$ and let $\bar{K}$ be a subgroup of the factor group $G/H$.  Then the set $K$ consisting of the union of all elements in the cosets of $H$ in $\bar{K}$ is a subgroup of $G$. To verify that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ let $a$ and $b$ belong to $K$ ($K$ is nonempty because it contains $H$).  Since $a$ and $b$ are in $K$ the cosets $aH$ and $bH$ are in $\bar{K}$ and $aH(bH)^{-1}=aHb^{-1}=ab^{-1}\; H$ is also a coset in $\bar{K}$.  Thus $ab^{-1}$ belongs to $K$.  Note that when $G$ is finite $|K|=|\bar{K}||H|.$

I don't understand in Example 15 above, how $K$ is consider to be "pulling back" a subgroup of a factor group $G/N$ and if that is related to the notion of the pull back described in properties (1) and (2) above.  Is "pulling back" in the example mean the same as being the pullback of $K$ in the example.  If so, can someone give some clarification in terms of a more detailed mathematical explanations please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the setup of Example 15 there is a natural homomorphism $\phi : G \to G/H$ defined by $\phi(x) = xH$.  Then we have a subgroup $\overline{K} < G/H$ and want to consider the set $K$ of all elements in a coset in $\overline{K}$; $K$ is "pulling back" $\overline{K}$ in that $K = \phi^{-1}(\overline{K})$ (so it is exactly the sense (2) you mentioned earlier).

(Edited to make $\overline{K}$ be the subgroup of $G/H$, which I'm pretty sure is what was intended.)

Comment: can I ask one more thing please., how do I write "$K$ consisting of the union of all elements in the cosets of $H$ in $K$ is a subgroup of $G$" in mathematical notations.

Comment: There's something not right about saying that at all... do you want $K$ to be the subgroup of $G/H$ or the subgroup of $G$?

Comment: sorry, the full sentence in example 15 should be:  "Then the set $K$ consisting of the union of all elements in the cosets of $H$ in $K$ is a subgroup of $G$".

Comment: I still don't really understand what that means.  It sounds like it is defining $K$ in terms of the cosets of $H$ in $K$, which requires you to already have $K$.  Maybe it should say "the set $K$ consisting of the union of all elements in the cosets of $H$ in $\overline{K}$", and have $\overline{K}$ be the name of the subgroup of $G/H$?

Comment: I made a typo.  The correct sentence should be "Then the set $K$ consisting of the union of all elements in the cosets of $H$ in $\bar{K}$ is a subgroup of $G$".  I have made the appropriate edit to the post.

Comment: Ah, OK.  So $K = \phi^{-1}(\overline{K})$ (I've edited my answer to say that now) and the other description they have given is $K = \bigcup_{aH \in \overline{K}}aH$.  That expression looks a bit weird, but it's because in the subscript we're thinking of $aH$ as an element of $G/H$ while beside it we are thinking of $aH$ as a subset of $G$.

Equvialently, $K = \{x \in G : \exists a \in G (x \in aH \wedge aH \in \overline{K})\}$.

Comment: also thank you for your explanations.  The example feel less mysterious to me now.